# generate 1 switchable table instead 3 table on 1 pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, datatables

I create 1 page that have 3 switch-able tables triggered by button, I using datatables as table plugin.

right now I succesfully make that 3 switch-able server-side tables triggered by button on 1 page, from end-user view it looks great and fully functional but when in console, page always trigger 3 same tables instead 1 table.

I not worried about small data generated by table, but when the time comes the data will stacked up to 1000+ data and that will be ridiculous thing to generate 1000+ data three times.

here's my slice of page :

```
<div class="panel-body">
   <ul class="nav nav-tabs alert col-md-12" id="myTab">
      <hr class="style14">
      <h4 class="header text-center col-md-8" id="texthead">Asset List</h4>
      <a class="btn btn-group btn-primary btn-sm changeTable" data-ajax="tableresponses.php" href="#table_asall" data-toggle="tab" onclick="changeText('All Assets Table')">All Assets</a>
      <a class="btn btn-group btn-primary btn-sm changeTable" data-ajax="tableresponses1.php" href="#table_asborrow" data-toggle="tab" onclick="changeText('Used Assets Table')">Used Assets</a>
      <a class="btn btn-group btn-primary btn-sm changeTable" data-ajax="tableresponses2.php" href="#table_asbroken" data-toggle="tab" onclick="changeText('Damaged Assets Table')">Damaged Assets</a>
      <hr class="style14">
   </ul>
   <div class="tab-content">
      <div id="table_asall" class="tab-pane fade active in"  >
         <div class="table-responsive wrap">
            <table class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0" >
                //*table code
            </table>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div id="table_asborrow" class="tab-pane fade">
         <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
               //*table code
            </table>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div id="table_asbroken" class="tab-pane fade">
         <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0" id="">
               //*table code*
            </table>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

so here's my js (that generated 3 tables)

```
var _ajaxURL = ""; 

$('.changeTable').on('click', function() {
    _ajaxURL = $(this).attr('data-ajax');

    $('table.display').DataTable({
        lengthChange: true,
        info: false,
        fixedHeader: true,
        select: true,
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "destroy": true,
        "sAjaxSource": _ajaxURL
    });

    $.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = function ( settings, helpPage, message ) { 
    console.log("Catch Error : Success");
    };

    function testUpdatedDatatable() {
        $('table.display').DataTable().clear().rows.add(response.url).draw();
    }
});
```

so if you check `$('table.display').DataTable({` that the main problem for generating 3 tables.

how can only generate 1 table instead 3 tables ?

Answer (score 0):

You could have 3 different php files containing one table each file. Then use the include function based on witch table you need

Comment: already using that method with ajax, the problem is 1 button always generated 3 tables not one

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, it only need global variable in target table and make value that change dynamically based on what button is pressed.

updated js

```
var _ajaxURL = ""; //you can initialize this global variable with some default value.

var table;

function changeTable(val){
        table = "'#"+(val)+"'";
    }

$('.changeTable').on('click', function() {
    _ajaxURL = $(this).attr('data-ajax');

    $('table').DataTable({
        lengthChange: true,
        info: false,
        fixedHeader: true,
        select: true,
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "destroy": true,
        "sDefaultContent": "Edit",      
        "sAjaxSource": _ajaxURL
    });

    $.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = function ( settings, helpPage, message ) { 
    console.log("Catch Error : Success");
    };

    function testUpdatedDatatable() {
        $('table.display').DataTable().clear().rows.add(response.url).draw();
    }
});
```

and add button value to like this

```
<a class="btn btn-group btn-primary btn-sm changeTable" data-ajax="tableresponses.php" href="#table_asall" data-toggle="tab" onclick="changeText('All Assets Table');changeTable('table_asall1');">All Assets</a>
```